# Getting started on making a new glyph

Tags: symbols, latin-modern

I would like to take the glyph for zero (0) from latin modern, and modify it in some way and then be able to use it as a new glyph in my LaTeX document. I.e.; it's not a new glyph for zero, it's just the shape I want to start with.

I do my work on (CentOS 7) Linux, using pdflatex in texlive to typeset my docs.

I've been spending a decent amount of time trying to figure this out myself, but not getting any traction so hoping someone here can point me in the right direction, to at least get me started.

The task I outlined above seems to me to me to cut to the heart of what I need to learn to be able to do the actual project I have in mind. For example, it avoids the obvious problems with using metafont and getting pixelated glyphs etc. of which there seems to be more "getting started" type helpful hints online.

Thanks!
James

Comment: Have you tried [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/)?  Have you searched [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: you could make a new type 1 font using a font editor and then regenerate the tex tfm metrics, but for just one character this seems like a lot of work and makes a document that's hard to distribute. Simpler would be to just use a graphical editor to make a small pdf file of your modified O and then `\includegraphics{myzero.pdf}` wherever you need the character

Comment: I have not tried FontForge, nor have I seached Graphic Design Stack Exchange, I'll follow some links and see what comes up. Thanks @Thérèse

Comment: Thanks @David-Carlisle, ultimately I don't want just one character, I want to make several (like a dozen or so) but all based off of the actual designs of the numerical characters 0-9 (and adding some more too).  At any rate, isn't one of the benefits of the open source nature of TeX and the fonts etc, that we can take existing work and mod it? I would like to do that as well as find a step-by-step tutorial on how to basically do what I'm after. Follow the recipe type of deal. Is that out there?